# How to track the change when the browser autofills a password in a form after you type the username

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to track an Autofill event in a form?

e.g. I Have a simple form with username, password and submit button.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
user: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
pass: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

now in JS (jQuery)

```
<script>
    $("#pass").change(function(){
    alert(1);
});

    $("#pass").blur(function(){
    alert(1);
});

    $("#pass").keyup(function(){
    alert(1);
});

    $("#pass").paste(function(){
    alert(1);
});

    $("#pass").focus(function(){
    alert(1);
});

</script>
```

All the events above are never triggered when the browsers remembers the form data (user and pass) and you type the user name and the browser auto-fills the password,

I want to trigger this change how do I without using timers or on blur/change event on the "User" input?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do it with a workaround: After every `onkeypress` event of the username field store the value of the password field. Then `onblur` of the username field, check if the value of the password field has changed.

Comment: I'm doing that already but I wanted to know if the browser fires any event or something

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such event. I'm assuming the `onchange` event is not fired.

Comment: unfortunately yes, I believe that when IE7 & 8 Disappear the placeholder attribute will fix this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

set timer to check if the field filled or not

**edit:** was not very attentive, have not noticed the last sentence, but only timer can be used